# CSS Sticky: Center element relative to its container

Tags: css, position, css-position, sticky

i try to center an element via position sticky. but i want to position it relative to its container element. the height of the container and the height of the sticky element are both variable. so in my example i have it at the position, where i want it to be, but it is not relative to its container.

but the element is clearly to far up top. it should only start within the container element, place itself at the center of the screen (top:50%, transform: translateY(-50%)) and *stick* as long as the container element goes. is that even possible?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 500px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  min-height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="sticky" style="height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
     
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="sticky" style="height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use the code snippet in your posts so that people can preview your code. Avoid using links as they become obsolete

Comment: yeah, i somehow *unlearned* on how to do it. but i figured it out again, the example is now on so.

Comment: You have two contradictory requirements: (1) place it at the center and (2) stick when the element goes. You cannot force an element to be in two places at the same time: at the center and then move from the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your additional comments I think I have a solution but it will require javascript. What you need to do so that the box respects it's parents boundries is to remove the `translateY` and just use a calculation of 50% minus the boxes height/2 as a distance to the screen boundries which is essentially what the translate did. Btw you had a lot of redundant postion relatives.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const div = document.querySelector('#sticky');
  if (div) {
    const divHeight = div.offsetHeight;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--div-height', `${divHeight}px`);
  }
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  align-items: start;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 300px 0;
}

.column {
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(50% - (var(--div-height) / 2));
  bottom: calc(50% - (var(--div-height) / 2));
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column center">
    <div id="sticky"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the height of the sticky dynamic or preset?

Comment: okay I did it. It will require js tho

Comment: so basically it means, there is no option, unless you go for js. thanks for clarification!

Comment: there is an option if the element has a preset height but other than that yeah